# create and persits BDMs using DAOs in Bonita

Tags: dao, bonita, data-access-object

How do i make use of the Bonita Provided Data Access Objects (DAOs) variables to create new instance of the Business Data Models (BDMs) Object and persist it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new object instance, simply declare it as part of your process business variables and initialize it:

- Select process pool
- Go to "Data" tab
- Select "Pool variables" sub-tab
- In "Business variables" section click on "Add..." button

You can initialize it either:

- Using the business variable default value:

  - In "Business variables" section click on "Add..." or "Edit..." button
  - In the "Default value" field click on the pencil icon to bring the Groovy script editor.
  - Use the Groovy script editor to create a script that create a new instance of your business variable Java object.
- or using an operation on a task:

  - Select the task.
  - Go to "Execution" tab, "Operations" sub-tab.
  - Click on "Add" button.
  - On the drop-down list on the left select your business variable.
  - Make sure the operation is set to "Instantiate with". If operation is different (e.g. "Takes value of"), click on the operation link and use the drop-down list to select "Instantiate with".
  - Click on the pencil icon on the right to bring the Groovy script editor.
  - Use the Groovy script editor to create a script that create a new instance of your business variable Java object.